# How to travlers JsonNode Array in play java twrill template

Tags: json, playframework, fasterxml

I am having an issue with Play Twirll template, I have passed JsonNode object to play template, I can access properties but in case of an array, I am not able to parse it.

```
<div class="dr-name">
<a href="#profile">
  @json.findPath("givenName").asText() 
  @json.findPath("lastName").asText(),
  json.findPath("educationDetails").elements().forEachRemaining((jsonNode) -> {});
  @for( a <- 1 to 10){
    println( "Value of a: " + a );
  }
</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you forget `@` before `json.findPath("educationDetails").elements()`